# How to Set Website Content Fit to All types of PC's Resolutions using Css

Tags: html, css

I am exhausted by working around this all the hours . The problem i am having is the website fits absolutely perfect in my laptop (All the Contents are being displayed without me scrolling the page ). Works perfectly for few other pc's aswell when i upload the website in test server.

But it gets zoomed in and scroll gets enabled for few pc's , i.e all the contents are not being displayed in single shot with few pc's resolutions , I have to scroll to see the missing out content.

How can i resolve this ?

I have my Css file with html and body set to `height,width: auto`  and few font sizes in rem's . Here's the Css part :

```
:root{
    --project_bg_color1 : #D81F26;
    --project_bg_color2 : #EEB51E;
    --text_colours : white; /* Also used for container background color */
    --btn_colours_1 : #D65421;
    --btn_colours_2 : #EDB41E;
    --bg_colors_elements : transparent; /* background transparent for buttons , containers , border elements etc... */
    --container_border_color : #e5765b;
    --black_text_color : #2D2D2D;
    --big_font_sizes : 1.2rem; /* Used in Headers , Tables and stake pages */
    --medium_font_sizes : 1rem; /* Used for contents */
    --medium_font_sizes_2 : 0.8rem;
    --font_family : Inter, -apple-system, BlinkMacSystemFont, PingFang SC, Hiragino Sans GB, noto sans, Microsoft YaHei, Helvetica Neue, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
}

html {
    -moz-text-size-adjust: none;
    -webkit-text-size-adjust: none;
    text-size-adjust: none;
    -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
    -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
    font-family: var(--font_family);
    line-height: 1.5;
    overflow: scroll;
    overflow-x: hidden;
    height: auto !important;
    width: auto !important;
}
::-webkit-scrollbar {
    width: 0;  /* Remove scrollbar space */
    background: var(--bg_colors_elements);  /* Optional: just make scrollbar invisible */
}
/* Optional: show position indicator in red */
::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
    background: var(--project_bg_color1);
}
body {
    background: url("../media/shapes.png") , linear-gradient(-0.7turn,var(--project_bg_color1), var(--project_bg_color2)) no-repeat center center fixed;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    height: auto !important;
    width: auto !important;
}
main {
    display: block;
}
```

**Please help me fix this . I am aiming to set the content display should be fit for all types of PC's and resolutions.**

Regards

Answer (score 1):

to begin with, get rid of all fixed width sizes, then you can set breakpoints using @media (max-width: x) where x will be the width at which the breakpoint will occur
for example
the base width of the block is 600 pixels, but using a media query for devices with a width of 900px and below, we change the class parameters

```css
body {
background-color: #333;
}
.nope {
width: 600px;
height: 50%;
position: absolute; 
background-color: aliceblue;
left: 20%;
}
@media (max-width: 900px) {
.nope {
width: 400px;
height: 30%;
position: absolute; 
background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
  <div class='nope'>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: if you add to everything else the values of blocks in such units as rem, em, vmin, vmax, vh then you will get an adaptive layout